# Associated Website not redirecting to Android Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, applinks

I am attempting to open an instant app from a URL by navigating to an associated link that has been tested in Android Studio and deployed to the app store. I've tested the following:

- I know the instant app is available because the Google Play page has "Try It" on it, which works effectively.
- App Links Assistant process fully configured, up to "Test App Links" which opens the IA and works correctly.
- assetlinks.json placed on my server and can be accessed by https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
- Activated the setting in the following URL: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en

Intent filters are also fully configured as per the instructions:

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, when I navigate to my URL, it doesn't redirect to my instant app as expected. Would anybody be able to direct me towards what might be wrong?

Comment: Is this specific to one browser? Do other instant apps work in it?

Comment: I've been trying to find another IA enabled URL to test, but I can't find any online. So I can't actually test that.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? do you think this is the same thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899984/instantapp-not-being-launched-when-clicking-on-link

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. If I enter the URL directly on a browser, it will not open an instant app, but the corresponding website. If however, I click on the URL from a link in another website or a text message it will open the instant app as expected. Weirdly, I am trying to launch from an NFC tag, which is treated as a URL entered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

@Jacobo I saw in another post someone mentioning that with [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) they fixed even for browser. I didn't test that yet because I'm actually trying to fix one step before. If I don't have the instant app cached or installed, my link is going to the website not to the InstantApp. Once I open the Instant manually or install the full version works fine but the non cached/ installed is not working. On the Google Play I already see the "Try now" button.